# FilePaths in Go

Tags: go, filepath

So this is the example from Programming in Go by Mark Summerfield.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"os"
"path/filepath"
"strings"
)

var britishAmerican = "british-american.txt"

func init() {
    dir, _ := filepath.Split(os.Args[0])
    britishAmerican = filepath.Join(dir, britishAmerican)
}

func main() {
    rawBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(britishAmerican)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    text := string(rawBytes)

    usForBritish := make(map[string]string)

    lines := strings.Split(text, "\n")
    fmt.Println(lines)
    for _, line := range lines {
        fields := strings.Fields(line)
        if len(fields) == 2 {
            usForBritish[fields[0]] = fields[1]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(usForBritish)
}
```

When I run this code with the init() func commented out, it works perfectly fine. If I leave it in I get this error:

```
open /var/folders/l6/rdqtyrfd303dw1cz8qvlfcvc0000gn/T/go-    build652175567/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/british-american.txt: no     such file or directory exit status 1
```

My question is, why does the `init()` func not grab the file from the appropriate directory?

Comment: Running `go fmt` on this piece of code would make it a bit easier for us to read it. You can do that in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/) as well.  – And it would also help to create an MCVE (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: Sorry for the formatting error. Here it is on the playground
https://play.golang.org/p/G8cUb6fZC9

Comment: you could edit your post - that makes it easier for the readers (then we don't have to follow a link)

Comment: Deliri, can you make an MCVE as @topskip mentions?  That is, a minimal piece of code that exemplifies the same unexpected behaviour you're seeing.  For instance, I don't think all the option parsing, and dealing with "-h" to show help text, is necessary to reproduce the problem.  The less extraneous code one has to read, the easier it is for others to help you.  And that's in your best interest, isn't it?

Comment: I can definitely do that. The reason I left the whole nine yards is 2 fold.
1) It's directly from his book, this way we can be assured that there are no silly mistakes.

2) I had a previous experience where I tried to keep the code short but what ended up happening was, I was attacked for wanting answers without providing the full scope of the question.
I guess I'm learning what the middle ground looks like.

Comment: Seems to me that you run main.go using `go run main.go`. Try to use `go build` and then run executable. Make sure that `british-american.txt` file is in the same directoryю

Comment: It works without init function because in that function britishAmerican variable overrides with directory of executable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the variable `britishAmerican` in the init function. Without `init()`, the program looks in the current directory (no path given, only the file name). With `init()`, it looks in the path where the executable is (`os.Args[0]`).  And with `go run main.go`, the directory with the executable is not the current working directory.

You should use `go build` to build the binary and then run it, or you should tell us what you want to achieve (as written by @RoninDev).

---

The MCVE I've mentioned could look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var filename = "foo.txt"

func init() {
    // change to true and things break
    if false {
        dir, _ := filepath.Split(os.Args[0])
        filename = filepath.Join(dir, filename)
    }
}

func main() {
       // requires a file 'foo.txt' in the current directory
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

It can (of course) be even shorter, but this should be enough for the others in the community to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the program is expecting a file called `british-american.txt` in the directory that the executable is in.

That is what the code in `init()` does - it finds the path the the executable and constructs a path to the dictionary relative to that.

I can see from your error message that you are using `go run` to run the code.  This makes a temporary executable in `/tmp` and runs that.  If you leave the `init()` code in then it will look for the dictionary in the `/tmp` directory and it won't find it.  If you take the `init()` code out it will look for the dictionary in the current directory and it will succeed.

If you want to use it as the author intended then use `go build` to build a binary and then run it - that will work.